# RedirectToAction to same controller

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

In My Asp.net MVC code, I sometimes write

```
return RedirectToAction("Manage", "User", new {Area = "Users", id = userId});
```

and sometimes

```
return RedirectToAction("Manage", new {id = userId});
```

Which is the best method to use if I am in the same User controller ?

Are there any pros and cons ?
I personally like the 2nd one as the routing takes care of the current controller and current area.

Comment: The first one can be reused in another controller. The second one is just a shorthand and a lazy/convenient way to do the same thing

Answer (score 1):

In the same controller you should use the second one, simply because it's shorter.
Behind the scenes both of them wil use RouteValuesHelpers.MergeRouteValues.

In case you like to explore this further: http://dotnetinside.com/en/type/System.Web.Mvc/Controller/5.2.0.0

Answer (score 1):

Neither one of them is better than the other if the action is on the same controller.

Overloaded methods exist to cover diverse needs.  RedirectToAction("ActionName", "ControllerName") exists to allow you to navigate to another controller.